# Hook up home theatre subwoofer to Cubase Elements 7 / Saffire Pro 40 rig?

Tags: mixing, speakers, cubase

I'm running a (relatively cheap) pair of M-Audio near-field monitors out of my Focusrite Saffire Pro 40. My DAW is Cubase Elements 7.

Recently, I was given a subwoofer from a home theatre setup that appears to have a built-in crossover as it accepts L/R speaker connections using speaker wire and outputs the same. I'm assuming it sends with a high-pass filter to any speakers hooked up to it. However, there is also a single RCA input on the rear.

Can I incorporate this subwoofer into my setup so I can mix with 2.1 channel sound? If I was to run a cable (line-level 1/4" to RCA) from the Saffire Pro 40's sends into the subwoofer, I would need to find a way to send only the desired range of bass frequencies from Cubase.

I don't believe it's desirable to run the monitors through the subwoofer since the "main" monitor accepts stereo RCA connections, but then connects to the other monitor with light gauge speaker wire. This seems like it would be a cumbersome solution that has an added risk of adding hum/noise through multiple adapters.

Is there a simple way to output only subwoofer-intended frequencies from within Cubase Elements 7?

Comment: Reopened because, although the OP is using an HT sub, the question is clearly about how to incorporate it into a production environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest method, plug to the sub, then to the monitors...

*…however,* as they were never designed to work together & the sub is from a home theatre setup of undisclosed quality, my instinctve guess is it will never sound better or more accurate than just the monitors.

I think you're just looking to create more trouble than it's worth.